# Why does the toolchain directive have no effect in this case?

Tags: go

I am trying to understand newly added `toolchain` directive in go.mod file and as I got it until now, it denotes which version of toolchain should be used in the current module. It, also, takes precedence over the go directive which defines the minimum version of the toolchain that those who include this module must have.

I tried to test this on an example with the new changes added to the golang `for` loops ([this](https://go.dev/blog/loopvar-preview)). And indeed, as I change the go directive from 1.21 to 1.22 and back, the behavior of the program changes. However, if I put the go directive to 1.21 and the toolchain directive to 1.22.0, I still get the behavior from 1.21. In other words, it looks like the toolchain directive has no any effect at all...

My go.mod file is as follows (ignore the module name, I am just testing it locally).

```
module HelloWorld

go 1.21

toolchain go1.22.0
```

`GOTOOLCHAIN` variable is set to auto. I am using golang `go1.22.0 windows/amd64` version.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It works as documented: the `go` line defines version-scoped language feature flags, the `toolchain` line defines what executables are run when you run the `go` command.

The document you linked on the changes to `for` loops states:

> To ensure backwards compatibility with existing code, the new semantics will only apply in packages contained in modules that declare `go 1.22` or later in their go.mod files.

This means, if it is set to `go 1.22` or newer, you get the new behavior, and if it is set to `go 1.21` or older you get the old behavior, full stop. It does not mention the `toolchain` directive.

The `toolchain` directive documentation states:

> In the standard configuration, the `go` command uses its own bundled toolchain when that toolchain is at least as new as the `go` or `toolchain` lines in the main module or workspace. For example, when using the `go` command bundled with Go 1.21.3 in a main module that says `go 1.21.0`, the `go` command uses Go 1.21.3. When the `go` or `toolchain` line is newer than the bundled toolchain, the `go` command runs the newer toolchain instead. For example, when using the `go` command bundled with Go 1.21.3 in a main module that says `go 1.21.9`, the `go` command finds and runs Go 1.21.9 instead.

Since you have Go 1.22 installed, setting `toolchain` to 1.21 or 1.22 has the same behavior: the built-in toolchain is the same version or newer, so that is what is used.

Comment: The documentation for `toolchain` says: "`go` command will use its own bundled toolchain when that toolchain is at least as new as the `go` or `toolchain` lines in the main module". However, the problem is that the `toolchain` line is set to 1.22.0 in go.mod (as my toolchain), so I am expecting the newest (1.22.0) behavior, but I am getting the one from 1.21 because of `go` line

Comment: Also, I do not understand the first paragraph in your answer. Yes, `go` line defines the version of the language (compiler) and, yes, `toolchain` line defines the version of the executables that are run with `go` command, but toolchain is the set of standard library, assembler, **compiler** etc. So, I would say that `toolchain` line includes `go` line. In documentation says: "`The go directive is an input into selecting which Go toolchain to run. See “Go toolchains” for details.`"

Comment: "go line defines the version of the language (compiler)" and "I would say that toolchain line includes go line" is where you're getting tripped up. The `go` line specifies which features are enabled, not what compiler et al is run. "language (compiler)" is probably what's confusing you - the language and compiler are two totally different things. Setting `go 1.21` and using the Go v1.22 compiler means that the v1.22 compiler runs, but uses the 1.21 language spec.